# UI microservice - No security are there any implications?

Tags: java, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud

This is probably super dumb.

**Are their any implications** of having a Microservice that simply serves a UI with no security?

I have security at the gateway level, the UI microservice simply serves the web app, there's nothing in the app that i would like to protect. I could go as far as ensuring that only the gateway can call it directly no other origin is allowed access.

I have Spring-Security on my class path but i've disabled it using:

application.yml

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

I haven't made any configuration changes to the security config for example this service has no class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

This service doesn't call anything else it just serves an Angular application contained in `/resource/public` with:

```
@RestController
public class AngularApplicationController {

      // serve UI
      @GetMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
      public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/";
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, This isn't super dumb question. As we know that Working with Microservices does not any fixed Pattern Or Design Consideration so it always depends on what is perfect for our Architecture.

As far as what is looks based on details you have provided, **There won't be any implications**.Provided as you also mentioned ensuring that only the gateway can call it directly no other origin is allowed access and accessing data doesn't need any kind of Roles of your Application.

For understanding more on Microservices Security you can check [Microservice's Security Questions](http://www.grahamlea.com/2015/07/microservices-security-questions/). Hope this information is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine as long as you are fine with non-logged user to be able to browse code of any part of the UI. Using security you are able to block access to some part of the UI if user is not logged or if he misses required role.